# Emacs set spacing for inline (end of line) comments

Tags: python, emacs, emacs23, dot-emacs

In the PEP 8 style guide for python, it is recommended that inline comments are separated by the rest of the line by [two spaces](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#inline-comments).  However, the default in Emacs is that running `comment-dwim` or `indent-for-comment` puts only one space between the end of the line and the comment.  Is there a way to change this default behavior in emacs?

I am running Emacs 23.3.1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
   (add-hook 'python-mode-hook
      (lambda () (set (make-local-variable 'comment-inline-offset) 2)))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can check emacs's documentation by `C-h v RET comment-inline-offset`, then you will find the answer as @And said.

Here's a simplified version:

```
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook
  (lambda () (setq-local comment-inline-offset 2)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `comment-start` to `" # "` (one space before, one afters).

```
M-x set-variable comment-start " # "
```

Comment: This _somewhat_ works, but has two problems:  First, it changes the commenting syntax for all lines (so when I comment out a line, they get commented with an extra space, un-aligning them with the rest of the text).  Second, if i run `comment-dwim` on the line with the inline comment again, it re-aligns the inline comment to have only one space.

Comment: Yea, I understand.  I had started digging through source last night, trying to find where the first space is inserted, but ran out of time.

Answer (score 1):

I think this might do what you want:

```
(defun my-comment-indent ()
  (interactive)
  (end-of-line)
  (let ((comment-column (+ 2 (current-column))))
    (comment-indent)))
```